# java.io.ioexception: cannot run program "arp": error=13, permission denied

Tags: android-studio, network-programming

Working on a project of network scan.There is an android application which will firstly discover the devices connected to the current network and then scans the whole network.

This is my code **`java file`** :

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    //final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    try {
        ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        String cmd;
        cmd= ARP_GET_IP_HW;
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("arp -a");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        //$NON-NLS-1$
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, commandLine);
        // DataBind ListView with items from ArrayAdapter

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In discovering devices (ARP table of the router)there is an error occurred :

```
java.io.ioexception: cannot run program "arp": error=13, permission denied
```

Comment: did you added Access Network State Permission in Manifest?

Comment: yes..  added  in the manifest file..